# How does copying dataframes in different ways affect memory consumption?

Tags: python, pandas, memory-profiling

I am trying figure out how different ways of copying pandas dataframes affect the memory consumption of a python script using the [memory_profiler](https://github.com/pythonprofilers/memory_profiler) package:

```py
from copy import deepcopy
import pandas as pd

@profile
def func2(df):
    return df.copy()


@profile
def func():
    a = [1] * (10 ** 6)
    df = pd.DataFrame({"val": a})
    df2 = pd.DataFrame({"val": a})

    df3 = func2(df)
    df4 = df
    df5 = df.copy(deep=False)

    df6 = df.copy(deep=True)
    df6.loc[:,"val"] = 2

    df7 = deepcopy(df)
    df7.loc[:,"val"] = 2


if __name__ == "__main__":
    func()
```

I run the script like this: `python -m memory_profiler mem_test.py`

And these are the results I get:

```
Filename: mem_test.py

Line #    Mem usage    Increment  Occurrences   Line Contents
=============================================================
     4  141.629 MiB  141.629 MiB           1   @profile
     5                                         def func2(df):
     6  141.641 MiB    0.012 MiB           1       return df.copy()


Filename: mem_test.py

Line #    Mem usage    Increment  Occurrences   Line Contents
=============================================================
     9   71.824 MiB   71.824 MiB           1   @profile
    10                                         def func():
    11   79.457 MiB    7.633 MiB           1       a = [1] * (10 ** 6)
    12  133.996 MiB   54.539 MiB           1       df = pd.DataFrame({"val": a})
    13  141.629 MiB    7.633 MiB           1       df2 = pd.DataFrame({"val": a})
    14
    15  141.641 MiB  141.641 MiB           1       df3 = func2(df)
    16  141.641 MiB    0.000 MiB           1       df4 = df
    17  141.641 MiB    0.000 MiB           1       df5 = df.copy(deep=False)
    18
    19  141.641 MiB    0.000 MiB           1       df6 = df.copy(deep=True)
    20  141.820 MiB    0.180 MiB           1       df6.loc[:,"val"] = 2
    21
    22  141.820 MiB    0.000 MiB           1       df7 = deepcopy(df)
    23  141.820 MiB    0.000 MiB           1       df7.loc[:,"val"] = 2
```

Things that confuse me:

- On line 12 and 13 we create identical data structures, yet the memory consumption is different
- How to read line 15? Mem usage and increment are equal as if memory consumption was zero before this line?
- I would expect line 19 or at least line 20 to cause notable increment in the memory consumption, yet it doesn't.
- Lines 22 and 23: the same as above

What is the rationale behind the observations above? How does the different ways of copying (assignment, shallow copy, deep copy and copy.deepcopy) pandas dataframes differ in memory consumption of a python script?

If the chosen way of studying memory consumption is not valid for these use case what method would you suggest instead?

I am using python 3.10.1 and the following version of pandas and memory_profiler:

```
pandas==1.4.3
memory-profiler==0.60.0
```

**EDIT:**

I ran the code provided in the answer by @Ahmed AEK and the results were similar with what I got using memory_profiler package. Since memory_profiler is using [psutil](https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil) under the hood I begin to wonder whether the issue could be related to OS since now two approaches using [psutil](https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil) both fail to give correct results.

Originally I used os x Catalina but now ran another test with Ubuntu. With Ubuntu I get similar results with both the original code and the code in the answer by @Ahmed AEK. So my best guess at the moment is that there appears to be a bug with psutil that for some reason manifests with the code and os x.

Answer (score 2):

i can tell just by inspection that the numbers you got are no where near correct, and you might want to submit an issue to the profiler module creators, anyway, you can request the program consumption from the operating system using `psutil`, and if you just want to do some simple benchmarking (non production code) then you can make a simple wrapper to print memory consumption by a line.

a disadvantage to this is that you get the memory before and after the execution of a line, and will not catch momentary memory spikes inside functions (although none should occur if the library creator is smart enough not to make one, as is the case for pandas)

```py
import os, psutil
import inspect
process = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
last_val = 0
def print_mem():
    # get memory
    mem = process.memory_info().rss / (1024 ** 2)  # in Mbytes
    global last_val
    increment = mem - last_val
    last_val = mem

    # dark magic to get line and line number in Cpython
    curframe = inspect.currentframe()
    calframe = inspect.getouterframes(curframe, 2)
    print('line_no =', calframe[1][2],'\t',end='')
    print(f'mem = {mem}\t\t',end='')
    print(f",increment = {increment}\t\t",end='')
    print('last_line = ',calframe[1][4][-2].strip())
```

integrating it into your benchmark is simple

```py
def func2(df):
    print_mem()
    b = df.copy()
    print_mem()
    return b


def func():
    print_mem()
    a = [1] * (10 ** 6)
    print_mem()
    df = pd.DataFrame({"val": a})
    print_mem()
    df2 = pd.DataFrame({"val": a})
    print_mem()
    df3 = func2(df)
    df4 = df
    df5 = df.copy(deep=False)
    print_mem()
    df6 = df.copy(deep=True)
    print_mem()
    df6.loc[:,"val"] = 2
    print_mem()
    df7 = deepcopy(df)
    print_mem()
    df7.loc[:,"val"] = 2
```

and the result makes sense

```
line_no = 33    mem = 52.5078125        ,increment = 52.5078125     last_line =  def func():
line_no = 35    mem = 60.453125     ,increment = 7.9453125      last_line =  a = [1] * (10 ** 6)
line_no = 37    mem = 68.16796875       ,increment = 7.71484375     last_line =  df = pd.DataFrame({"val": a})
line_no = 39    mem = 75.80078125       ,increment = 7.6328125      last_line =  df2 = pd.DataFrame({"val": a})
line_no = 26    mem = 75.80078125       ,increment = 0.0        last_line =  def func2(df):
line_no = 28    mem = 83.43359375       ,increment = 7.6328125      last_line =  b = df.copy()
line_no = 43    mem = 83.43359375       ,increment = 0.0        last_line =  df5 = df.copy(deep=False)
line_no = 45    mem = 91.06640625       ,increment = 7.6328125      last_line =  df6 = df.copy(deep=True)
line_no = 47    mem = 91.25390625       ,increment = 0.1875     last_line =  df6.loc[:,"val"] = 2
line_no = 49    mem = 98.890625     ,increment = 7.63671875     last_line =  df7 = deepcopy(df)
```

a minor remark that executing the same function twice can have different memory consumption due to some extra stuff a library might load the first time you are executing a function, (probably the library is lazy-loading its functions)

alternatively commercial profilers may be able to catch momentary spikes, but i am only talking about a copy-paste workaround here, as monitoring these spikes requires another process to be monitoring your python process.

Comment: I added new information to my question after testing the code kindly provided here.

Comment: @jjei maybe the operating system takes time on osx to update its data, so if "running the benchmark correctly" is your only goal, you can add a one second time.sleep inside the print_mem function before requesting the memory from os.

Comment: @jjei you should also try looking at the vms instead of rss in the memory information, it may produce more accurate result.